# get_where para PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, array, pdo

Quero mudar o get_where pra mysql ou PDO, mas não sei! Help ...!

```
public function get_where($table = '', $where = NULL, $limit = NULL, $offset = NULL)
{
    if ($table !== '')
    {
        $this->from($table);
    }

    if ($where !== NULL)
    {
        $this->where($where);
    }

    if ( ! empty($limit))
    {
        $this->limit($limit, $offset);
    }

    $result = $this->query($this->_compile_select());
    $this->_reset_select();
    return $result;
}
```

Necessito de ajuda pra mudar:

```
$this->db->get_where('settings' , array('type' => 'site_name'))->row()->description;
```

para PDO.

Mudei as seguintes informações no banco de dados

Tabela: settings;

type => option_name;

site_name => title

description => option_value

Comment: O que você sabe de SQL?

Comment: Na teoria (obs: descrevendo como funciona) nada, porém na prática me viro nos trinta e acaba dando certo muita coisa, porém a pergunta em si não há relevância em questão do assunto publicado. Enfim, poderia me ajudar?

Comment: até tentei arriscar colocar assim: $db->query('SELECT option_value FROM settings WHERE array("option_name" => "title") DESC'); porém, não funcionou

Comment: Parece ter mais algumas configurações nessa classe, só com esse código não tem como saber. Aparece algum erro?

Comment: A sintaxe do SQL é independente do PHP e é inteiramente relevante à pergunta. Comece lendo o básico da linguagem antes de tentar fazer qualquer coisa. Lembre-se que funcionar não é o mesmo que estar certo. Talvez com isso já consiga começar: [link](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-clausula-where/37645)

Comment: Hum, bem, você poderia ajeitar para mim o $db->query('SELECT option_value FROM settings WHERE array("option_name" => "title") DESC');

Comment: Isso aí é algum framework?

Comment: não é um framework